# Enterprise D's Deck 1-Lower - what's it like?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise

In ST:TNG, we actually don't get to see most of the Enterprise-D. Specifically a lot of Deck 1 is unexplored, and more specifically, Deck 1-Lower. [Here](https://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/blueprints/whitefire-enterprise-ncc-1701d/whitefire-enterprise-ncc-1701d-sheet-4.jpg) are some blueprints of it.

I was wondering if there has ever been some official, or even fan-initiated, visualization of Deck 1 Lower; and failing that - some textual description (more than a single sentence) of what's it used for.

Answer (score 4):

The closest I know of is Stage 9's Virtual Enterprise-D, which was cancelled due to a cease & desist letter from Paramount. It was a reproduction of the Enterprise-D, including many areas only partially seen, such as crew quarters, the main shuttlebay, and the connective areas of Deck 1.

Although this game/simulation can't be legally acquired anymore, there are a few videos of people who had played it. I've queued up [one such video](https://youtu.be/FnQ-BS7Ui54?t=796) to the point where the player leave the bridge toward the observation deck. You can see the entrance to Deck 1 Lower, but unfortunately it's inaccessible as it was never developed before the project was shut down.

Comment: Actually, I had just watched that video before asking here...

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Unfortunately I think this is as close as you might get to an answer. Unless there's a novel or something that describes it well.

Answer (score 2):

We see a brief scene of the underside of deck 1 in the TNG episode, *[Brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brothers_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))*.

Data takes control of the Enterprise and locks everyone out of the bridge. Two of the crew attempt to enter the bridge through an access panel on the bottom of deck 1. They are thwarted when Data creates a force-field at the access panel.

Not sure if this is quite what you want since it shows briefly what is just *below* deck 1 rather than other rooms and corridors on deck 1.

Answer (score 0):

All most all that stuff on the blueprints is behind bulkheads and are not common traffic areas.  They are full of computers and machines and such.

For the most part Deck 1 is the Bridge, the Observation Lounge and the Captain's ready room.  We sure have never seen the Communication Office or the Stairs.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.